# How to right align and round floats using fstrings

Tags: python

This doesn't work, is it possible to add more than one formatting code to an fstring.  I want to round to two decimal places then right align the output.

```
nums = [
    12.3292,
    14.98717,
    5.8291,
    3.0091,
    99.99901
]


for i,num in enumerate(nums):
    print(f"{i=:03} {num:>10 0.2f} {num:>10 0.2f}")
```

Comment: floats are already right-aligned so use `{num:>10.2f}` or just `{num:10.2f}`

Comment: And it is possible to specify both thing. `f{num:>10.2f}` right align it (the `>` is useless since it is indeed the default). `f{num:<10.2f}` left align it. So, you can see that you can specify both even if you don't need to for right align

Comment: @MarkTolonen thanks, works a treat